# Why are my commits to organization's private repo not showing on my profile page?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have cloned my company's private repo in an organization. (no fork)

I have created a new branch called 'fix' in my local, and wrote some code.

Made 60 commits.

Committed, then pushed by using `git push origin fix`

Even when the pull request is merged, I do not see those green commit boxes in my profile.

Why aren't my commits showing on my profile page as green blocks, and how can I get them to show (if not possible, what should I do differently next time)?

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub, make sure you enable private contributions on your profile. Click "Contribution settings" and then "Private contributions."

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, I have it turned on. Any other ideas? someone said my commits could be accidentally squashed? and I should use reflog? But my branch on the private repo has been deleted now

Comment: If you have them squashed, it does show only as one. Check the branch on where you merged the pull request and if those 60 commits are there, then they aren't squashed.

Comment: I have the same problem...Any idea how to show contributions even when made to organization private repository?

Answer (score 0):

Only commits made to the `default branch` are shown in the graph.

> Check the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#commits).